# How to create new ETH account with API

Tags: python

I'm new to the study of `Blockchain` and most recently began to study `Ethereum`.

I create a web application, and I need to create an `ETH` address for each new user. But the important condition is that I do not want to deploy my own node.
I want to use some external `API` for this simple task.

Can anyone advise such a service?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Generating your private keys through a 3rd-party service is a bad idea. They now control your account. What is your end goal? Maybe it can be done a different way. Why can't users just bring their own account?

Comment: The purpose of the service is extremely simple - it is possible to buy tokens for BTC and ETH

In the case of BTC, I just generate a reedem code, but I do not know how to deal with ETH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are external API's for generating address. They provide much more api's that just of address creation. Have a look at their documentation:

- [Blockcypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#address-endpoint)
- [CoinPayments](https://www.coinpayments.net/apidoc-get-deposit-address)

Comment: Thank you!
I've already seen Blockcypher, and I saw an opportunity to generate an address, but I did not see a response in the response as a password or anything like that. Only public, private, address

Comment: So what's the problem? The public, private keys, and address are all that you need. You can use your private key to unlock your account, you don't need a password.